# Mongoose not saving data to mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm building a shopping cart using JavaScript, MongoDB & Node.js. I've been able to save all the site's products, users & sessions so far. After I complete my checkout form, my inputs should be saved to MongoDB. I should be able to see "orders" among the db collections. But when I type `show collections` into the command line, only *products, users, sessions* are shown.

This is the error message:

```
ValidationError: Order validation failed
    at MongooseError.ValidationError (/Users/vynguyen/shopping-cart/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:23:11)
    at model.Document.invalidate (/Users/vynguyen/shopping-cart/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1524:32)
    at /Users/vynguyen/shopping-cart/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1399:17
    at validate (/Users/vynguyen/shopping-cart/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:706:7)
    at /Users/vynguyen/shopping-cart/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:750:9
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (/Users/vynguyen/shopping-cart/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:711:19)
    at /Users/vynguyen/shopping-cart/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1397:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

This is my Mongoose schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schema = new Schema({
    user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    cart: {type: Object, required: true},
    address: {type: String, required: true},
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    paymentId: {type: String, required: true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', schema);
```

This is my index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Cart = require('../models/cart');

var Product = require('../models/product');
var Order = require('../models/order');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var successMsg = req.flash('success')[0];
    Product.find(function(err, docs) {
        var productChunks = [];
        var chunkSize = 3;
        for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i += chunkSize) {
            productChunks.push(docs.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
        }
        res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Shopping Cart', products: productChunks, successMsg: successMsg, noMessages: !successMsg});
    });
});

router.get('/add-to-cart/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    var productId = req.params.id;
    var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart ? req.session.cart : {});

    Product.findById(productId, function(err, product){
        if (err) {
            return res.redirect('/');
        }
        cart.add(product, product.id);
        req.session.cart = cart;
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});

router.get('/shopping-cart', function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.session.cart) {
        return res.render('shop/shopping-cart', {products: null});
    }
    var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart);
    res.render('shop/shopping-cart', {products: cart.generateArray(), totalPrice: cart.totalPrice});
});

router.get('/checkout', function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.session.cart) {
        return res.redirect('/shopping-cart');
    }
    var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart);
    var errMsg = req.flash('error')[0];
    res.render('shop/checkout', {total: cart.totalPrice, errMsg: errMsg, noError: !errMsg});
});

router.post('/checkout', function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.session.cart) {
        return res.redirect('/shopping-cart');
    }
    var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart);

    var stripe = require("stripe")(
      "**hidden**"
    );

    stripe.charges.create({
      amount: cart.totalPrice * 100,
      currency: "usd",
      source: req.body.stripeToken,
      description: "Test Charge"
    }, function(err, charge) {
        if (err) {
            req.flash('error', err.message);
            return res.redirect('/checkout');
        }
        var order = new Order({
            user: req.user,
            cart: cart,
            address: req.body.address,
            name: req.body.name,
            paymentId: charge.id
        });
        order.save(function(err, result) {
            req.flash('success', 'Successfully bought product!');
            req.session.cart = null;
            res.redirect('/');  
        });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: There isn't one. After logging in & checking out I'm just not able to see the data in my mongo shell (after calling db.orders.find())

Comment: Did you try to print err and result?

Comment: @Peter G: it is saved here: order.save(function(err, result) {
   req.flash('success', 'Successfully bought product!');
   req.session.cart = null;
   res.redirect('/'); 
  });

Comment: I mean, the real data. Not some message.

Comment: @israel.zinc: can you show me how to check if the data is saved or not (other than using db.orders.find())?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137397/discussion-between-israel-zinc-and-vnguyen).

Comment: @israel.zinc: I just updated the post with the error message. I think we talked about this the other day. Any hint?

Comment: Try to remove some fields and see what happens.

Comment: Finally solved it. I consoled every field in the order & found a syntax error with the req.body.address field in my checkout form. After fixing the error the database is now showing my order. Thanks so much everyone, especially israel.zinc for your time.

Comment: I'm glad you solved man.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is how I solved the error:

I consoled out every field inside the order object and found a syntax error in my checkout.form that is linked to req.body.address. After fixing the error 'order' is now showing in my db collections.

Phew! Kudos to israel.zinc for spending time chatting with me to get to the bottom of the issue.